# Saving hash as json and getting it back trouble in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash

I'm saving the result of this method to file in json format:

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
    ...

    def getting_hash
        video = Video.new
        video.id = 12
        video.title = "How to make it work?"
        video.desc = "No idea..."
        video_hash = Hash.new
        video_hash[video.id] = {id: video.id, title: video.title, desc: video.desc}
        write_to_file(video_hash)
    end

    ...
end
```

So for saving to the file I use:

```
  def write_to_file(model)
    path  = "#{Rails.root}/public/my_file.cache"
    open(path, 'w') { |f|
      f.write(model.to_json)
    }
  end
```

Seems like vanilla, but when I use:
     read_from_file(my_file.cache)

```
  def read_from_file(file_name)
    path = Rails.root + "public/#{file_name}"
    file = File.read(path)
    hash_to_return = JSON.parse(file)
  end
```

It returns not the hash, but an array!

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<Array:0x007f1926325460>):
```

And when I check:

```
["12", {"id"=>"12", "title"=>"How to make it work?", "description"=>"No idea..."}]
```

I don't understand how is that possible, because if I use variables it makes everything perfect like:

```
(byebug) test = {"12":{"id":12,"title":"How to make it work?","desc":"No idea..."}}
{:"12"=>{:id=>12, :title=>"How to make it work?", :desc=>"No idea..."}}
(byebug) test2 = test.to_json
"{\"12\":{\"id\":12,\"title\":\"How to make it work?\",\"desc\":\"No idea...\"}}"
(byebug) JSON.parse(test2)
{"12"=>{"id"=>12, "title"=>"How to make it work?", "desc"=>"No idea..."}}
```

Please, help me with getting correct hashes back! Any ideas are highly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

```
JSON::ParserError (lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                         {"12"=>{:id=>"12", :title=>
                     (right here) ------^
):
```

**UPDATE 2**
my_file.cache's output:
{"12":{"id":"12","title":"How to make it work?","description":"No idea..."},"14":{"id":"14","title":"Yoga","description":"Guide"}}

**UPDATE 3**
For now I've overriden this situation with: `video_hash = Hash[*hash_to_return.flatten]` and got the desired format.
So back home I'll try with running plain ruby file (as rwold said) and also I'll test the approach by ahmed eshra.
Sincere thanks to all who participated!

***UPDATE 4***

I tried my code as a plain ruby file outside Rails (with slight modifications) and it worked perfectly!

Comment: where is `getting_hash` used?

Comment: @apneadiving class VideosController < ApplicationController

Comment: how? we dont see this in your code samples

Comment: @apneadiving updated

Comment: what if you do `write_to_file({id: 12, title: "title", desc: "desc"})`?

Comment: JSON::ParserError (lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                         {"12"=>{:id=>"12", :title=>
                     (right here) ------^
): I'll add this to the question with pretty formatting

Comment: seems it is saved as ruby hash, not json

Comment: look update 2 then, please

Comment: I confirm: what is stored is a ruby hash, its not json. Not sure why though, is it the proper file? Is to json really called?

Comment: My clue is that when it is called for variable it contains "{\"12\":{\"id\":12,\"title\":\"How to make it work?\",\"desc\":\"No idea...\"}}", but in file - look in the question.

Comment: the code looks good, you sure you send the proper file name to `read_from_file` ?

Comment: unfortunately...

Comment: `File.read("foo.json")` => `"{\"12\":{\"id\":\"12\",\"title\":\"How to make it work?\",\"description\":\"No idea...\"},\"14\":{\"id\":\"14\",\"title\":\"Yoga\",\"description\":\"Guide\"}}"` and 
`JSON.parse(File.read("foo.json"))` => `{"12"=>{"id"=>"12", "title"=>"How to make it work?", "description"=>"No idea..."}, "14"=>{"id"=>"14", "title"=>"Yoga", "description"=>"Guide"}}`

Comment: I just tried your code, including file IO, and it worked perfectly. Either there's a subtle difference between the example input you've given us (`test`) and what your code is actually generating, or there's a bug in your stack that has been fixed in later versions (I'm using Rails 5.1, ruby 2.4.0; json 1.8.3). You might find it helpful to share the versions you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think passing the object itself with to_json conversion, is better for what you need and it will be saved as hash.

```
def getting_hash
    video = Video.new
    video.id = 12
    video.title = "How to make it work?"
    video.desc = "No idea..."
    # Removing the hash conversion step
    write_to_file(video)
end
```

Comment: It doesn't explain why json parsing fails, but still it works! Thanks!